# Find all ocurrences after specific string in another string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a response from an API (actually is a composite message from AWS lex)  and it look like this:

```
 '{\"messages\":[{\"type\":\"PlainText\",\"group\":1,\"value\":\"Great!\"},{\"type\":\"PlainText\",\"group\":2,\"value\":\"Please click here.\"}]}'
```

I can't change the response to a string, and I need to get from that string the text of:

**"Great!"** and **"Please click here."**

Basically anything after => `"value\":\"` and before `\"}`

I have tried plenty of approaches but couldn't hit the nail.
Is there any way to do this, I even tried writing a regex but what I could get was the string before and not the actual text I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert your JSON API output to a JS object.  Then, we can iterate all messages in the array and extract the values.

```js
var input = '{\"messages\":[{\"type\":\"PlainText\",\"group\":1,\"value\":\"Great!\"},{\"type\":\"PlainText\",\"group\":2,\"value\":\"Please click here.\"}]}';
var x = JSON.parse(input);
var arr = x.messages.map(item => item.value)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Where do these names `x` and `e` come from?

Comment: @Spectric Nice lambda stuff...studying it now.

Comment: How did you manage to get 411k without knowing lambdas?

Comment: @RoboRobok I am only silver rated in JS.  Most of my rep comes from SQL, Java, and R.  Well, I certainly know lambdas in Java.

Comment: @Spectric I know, but I'm still quite shooketh. That's some juvenile JS out there.

Comment: How didn't I thought about JSON.parse? this is great @TimBiegeleisen thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you just use `JSON.parse()`?

```js
const responseJson = '{"messages":[{"type":"PlainText","group":1,"value":"Great!"},{"type":"PlainText","group":2,"value":"Please click here."}]}';
const response = JSON.parse(responseJson);
const values = response.messages.map(message => message.value);

// values is now ['Great!', 'Please click here.']
```